# How to access formControlName in ngFor inside ngFor (nested formArray)?

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-formbuilder

I am a beginner of Angular 2. I am trying to create a table with dynamic form, table is created and value also bind but I am not able to access value in formControlName, tried below code but it did not work.

could someone please help me where I am doing wrong in the below code

**HTML**

```
<tbody formArrayName="timetable">
     <tr *ngFor="let child of timetableForm.controls.timetable.controls; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
        <td *ngFor="let period of child.controls.periods.controls;let j = index;" [formGroupName]="j">
            {{period.controls.day.value}} <!-- bind is working fine -->
            <input type="text" [formControlName]="day">  <!-- error -->                               
        </td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

**TS**

```
ngOnInit(){
this.tableForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      timetable: this.formBuilder.array([
             this.formBuilder.group({
                    periods: this.formBuilder.array([
                        this.formBuilder.group({
                            subject_id:10,
                            timing_id:11,
                            day:'Monday'
                        }),
                        this.formBuilder.group({
                            subject_id:10,
                            timing_id:11,
                            day:'Tuesday'
                        }),
                        this.formBuilder.group({
                            subject_id:10,
                            timing_id:11,
                            day:'Wednesday'
                        }),
                        this.formBuilder.group({
                            subject_id:10,
                            timing_id:11,
                            day:'Thursday'
                        }),
                        this.formBuilder.group({
                            subject_id:10,
                            timing_id:11,
                            day:'Friday'
                        })
                    ])
                }),
                this.formBuilder.group({
                    periods: this.formBuilder.array([
                        this.formBuilder.group({
                            subject_id:10,
                            timing_id:11,
                            day:'Monday'
                        }),
                        this.formBuilder.group({
                            subject_id:10,
                            timing_id:11,
                            day:'Tuesday'
                        }),
                        this.formBuilder.group({
                            subject_id:10,
                            timing_id:11,
                            day:'Wednesday'
                        }),
                        this.formBuilder.group({
                            subject_id:10,
                            timing_id:11,
                            name:'Thursday'
                        })
                    ])
                })
            ])
         });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use `formControlName ="day"` instead of `[formControlName]="day"`

Comment: @TanDuong Already tried this one but its showing this error "ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'timetable -> timetable'"

Comment: if it is possible to add your code to plunker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing I noticed

```
this.formBuilder.group({
      subject_id:10,
      timing_id:11,
      name:'Thursday'
      ^^^^
 it should be day
})
```

Secondly, why are you using `timetableForm` in template whilst you created `tableForm` in component?

Thirdly, you should use `formControlName="day"` instead of `[formControlName]="day"` as was mentioned in comments.

Finally, you forgot to wrap your child array in `formArrayName="periods"`. To do that you can use `ng-container` as shown below:

```
<table [formGroup]="tableForm">
    <tbody formArrayName="timetable">
        <tr *ngFor="let child of tableForm.controls.timetable.controls; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
            <ng-container formArrayName="periods">
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                       add this
                <td *ngFor="let period of child.controls.periods.controls;let j = index;" [formGroupName]="j">
                    {{period.controls.day.value}}
                    <input type="text" formControlName="day">
                </td>
            </ng-container>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/yZNgNQbS1LxYIgoe1ioG)**